# Why is "ф" used almost exclusively in loan words?

Tags: орфография, согласные

It is a common bit of trivia that the letter Ф is an extremely reliable indicator that you are looking at a loan word. Wikipedia tries its best at mentioning a couple of words of Slavic origin, but they are [few and far between](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4):

> В современном русском языке буква «Ф» используется почти исключительно в заимствованиях, обозначает глухой твёрдый звук [ф] или мягкий [ф'] (перед «е», «ё», «и», «ю», «я» и «ь»). В словах славянского происхождения «Ф» встречается в звукоподражаниях (*фукать, фыркать*) или в словах, сильно изменивших свою звуковую и письменную форму (*филин, Фили*).

My question is: *why* is that the case? Certainly /f/ an extremely common sound in Russian. It is an integral part of the Russian phonological grammar — and in fact, there'd be no reason to introduce a dedicated letter for a sound that is not. It'd be rather silly indeed. I struggle to think of anything remotely similar in other languages.

So what's the deal here? Why is it that even after centuries have passed, and even after Ѳ has been discarded for good, Ф has still barely got any traction outside of loan words?

Comment: there is Russian names with that letter so it has been used long before Photograph. Consider who created Russian Alphabet. Кирилл и Мефодий, you have to consider ties with Greek language especially in Russian Orthodox Church.

Answer (score 10):

The reason why a special letter was introduced for a foreign sound is quite simple, the classical Cyrillic alphabet included *all* the letters of the Greek alphabet, including `Ѳ` and `Ф`.

In the modern Russian, [f] is *not* used almost exclusively in loan words, as you put it, it is used in numerous original Russian words and in different suffixes, only it is spelled like `в`, not like `ф`. Before a voiceless consonant the letter `в` is pronounced as [f] in words like `завтра`, `вчера`, `второй`, `вперёд`, etc. In the end of a word before a pause it is also [f], like in `котов`, `зубов`, `узнав`, `дав`, `написав` etc.

But the reason why /f/ was not a part of the Proto-Slavic inventory of phonemes has no possible answer, asking about it is like asking why Slavic languages lack interdentals, like the English /ð/, or emphatic consonants, like the Arabic /sˤ/.

Comment: вчера definitely doesn't pronounce в as ф, since it's followed by the звонкая согласная. thus even if фчера would exist in Russian language, it'd actually sound like вчера.

Comment: @Volodya - Actually, `ч` is a voiceless consonant, глухая согласная. Look at the [IPA transcription of "вчера" in Wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) or [listen to the word](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Ru-%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.ogg) as it is pronounced by a native speaker of Russian.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5):

A more correct question would be, why other Indo-European languages **have** /f/. This is because the Proto-Indo-European language had no such sound.

For example, in English word-initial /f/ evolved from PIE /p/, in Greek the evolution was from PIE /b<sup>h</sup>/ via /p<sup>h</sup>/.

Answer (score -2):

Russian language have few own words with "Ф", because we prefer more strong sound "В". But in other countries F is one of most popular letter. Gradually this words going in our language and today we have more foreign words with "Ф" then own.

Comment: Strange explanation. Do you always pronounce ending "В" in family names like Иванов, Петров, Сидоров?

Comment: Very soft sound "В" more strong then "Ф". Nobody talk Иваноф, Петроф, Сидороф.

Comment: You're wrong. It's pronounced exactly like "иваноф" (at least in the most common dialect).

Comment: Yes, it's true. But first question about letter not pronounce. And I not see conflict with my answer. In Иванов, Петров, Сидоров - "Ф" - softened final sound. In French last half of word in generally not say))) But can you give example with pronounce "Ф" instead "В" in start of word?